# what's wrong with my applescript-syntax error: expected "then", etc. but found class name

Tags: macos, automation, outlook, applescript

```
tell application "System Events"
set window_check to false
repeat until (window_check)
    set frontApp to name of first application process whose frontmost is true
    if frontApp is "Microsoft Outlook" then
        tell process "Microsoft Outlook"
            if class of front window is draft window then 
            --syntax error: expected "then", etc. but found class name
                display dialog "draft"                  
                set window_check to true
            end if
        end tell
    end if
end repeat
end tell
```

when i save the script, it pop a error "syntax error: expected "then", etc. but found class name" (see the comment for error location)

what's wrong with my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell Outlook, not System Events...

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook" to return class of front window is draft window
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided that, I don't have Microsoft Outlook installed, at the moment, I managed to compile this by removing "window" after "draft".

```
 if class of front window is draft then
```

Take a look at the AppleScript dictionary of Outlook to see how it identifies classes: "draft" alone seems already a class identifier.

Comment: Hi MrAsterisco. I replace "draft window" to "draft". But get the Result:
error "The variable draft is not defined." number -2753 from "draft"

Comment: Hi MrAsterisco. I replace "draft window" to "draft". 
But get the Result:
error "The variable draft is not defined." number -2753 from "draft". 
I have looked the AppleScript dictionary of Outlook, and only find the class - 
"draft window n [inh. window > item] : A message draft window.
responds to
save."

Comment: I think adayzdone is right. You should ask these types of questions to System Events, not to the application directly.